# Add click event to Div and go to first link found

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I think I've been too much time looking at this function and just got stuck trying to figure out the nice clean way to do it.

It's a jQuery function that adds a click event to any `div` that has a `click` CSS class. When that `div.click` is clicked it redirects the user to the first link found in it.

```
function clickabledivs() {
    $('.click').each(
        function (intIndex) {
            $(this).bind("click", function(){
                window.location = $( "#"+$(this).attr('id')+" a:first-child" ).attr('href');
            });
        }
    );
}
```

The code simply works although I'm pretty sure there is a fairly better way to accomplish it, specially the selector I am using: `$( "#"+$(this).attr('id')+" a:first-child" )`. Everything looks long and slow. Any ideas?

Please let me know if you need more details.

PS: I've found some really nice jQuery benchmarking reference from Project2k.de here: 
http://blog.projekt2k.de/2010/01/benchmarking-jquery-1-4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how many of these `div.click` elements you have, you may want to use event delegation to handle these clicks. This means using a single event handler for all divs that have the `click` class. Then, inside that event handler, your callback acts based on which `div.click` the event originated from. Like this:

```
$('#div-click-parent').click(function (event)
{
    var $target = $(event.target); // the element that fired the original click event
    if ($target.is('div.click'))
    {
        window.location.href = $target.find('a').attr('href');
    }
});
```

Fewer event handlers means better scaling - more `div.click` elements won't slow down your event handling.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great and quick answers. The function could definitely be optimized much more. I'll stick with the one Bears will eat you suggests. Just one event for all the div clicks. Thank you!!

Comment: Just a quick tweak, "if ($target.is('div.click')" needs an extra ) at the end. Thanks again!

Comment: thanks for this simple solution, was trying to make div clickable based on h3 title a href inside it and this works!

Answer (score 5):

optimized delegation with jQuery 1.7+

```
$('#div-click-parent').on('click', 'div.click', function () {
   window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of binding all the clicks on load, why not bind them on click? Should be much more optimal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.click').click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).children('a:first').attr('href');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you see anything about binding the clicks on load?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like;

```
$('.click').click(function(e){
  window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: +1 because you were the first not to assume it was an immediate child!

Comment: I'm pretty sure he just means `'a'` instead of `a`.